# Disable a custom button on page after click

Tags: visualforce, related-list, button, list-button

We have a button list button on Order (Bill Now Button). It opens a VF page and executes some actions. After clicking the button, it take a while to be redirected to the VF Page. Some users click it twice or more. When clicked more than once, it displays an this error.

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8016E0000001vPJQAY; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: [] 
>   Error is in expression '{!init}' in component  in page jvco_billnow: Class.JVCO_BillNowLogic.tickBillNow: line 102, column 1 
>   Class.JVCO_BillNowLogic.init: line 72, column 1

There's no effect on the code execution but we are getting this nasty error. Is it possible to disable the list button after a click? This related list is on account. 
Check the image below.[image: Order Related list on Account]

Answer (score 1):

By making the content Source of custom button as 'Execute JavaScript' and calling your VF page then can help. Code for the button:

```
this.disabled = true;<span> </span><font color="#339966">//Disables the button</font>
this.className = 'btnDisabled';/<font color="#339966">/Apply disabled button style(Optional)</font>
window.location='/apex/yourVFPage';<font color="#339966">//Call your VF page here</font>
```

Let me know this helps!!

Comment: I guess Op is referring to disable the button in related list, not visualforce

Comment: @RahulSharma: Yes I'm referring to disable the button in the related list.

Comment: @jema Have updated the answer. You can try the same and let me know this works!

Comment: @KhushbooDua: Hi, will try this :). But one thing concerns me, on-click javascripts will not be supported in lightning. Nonetheless, I'll update you if it works.